# Using nested Classes in C# and C++ - Why and When?

Tags: c#, c++

In my self-directed efforts to bring my programming skills and habits into the 21st Century (migrating from Pascal & Fortran to C# and C++), I've been studying a fair amount of available source code.  So far as I have been able to determine, Classes are unique 'standalone' entities (much like their Function ancestors).

I have, however, run across numerous instances where one or more Classes are nested within another Class.  My 'gut instinct' in this regard is that doing so is simply due to extremely poor methodology - however, I'm not yet familiar enough with modern OOP methodology to truly make such a determination.

Hence, the following overlapping questions:

Is there legitimate reasoning for nesting one Class inside another?  And, if so, what is the rationale in doing so as opposed to each Class being wholly independent?

(Note: The examples I've seen have been using C#, but it seems that this aspect applies equally to C++.)

Comment: They can be useful in generic classes, that way every "version" of your generic class will have a different type associated with it (i.e.: `Generic<int>.Nested` is different from `Generic<float>.Nested`).

Comment: @Antonijn that doesn't explain why it's nested though.  Why not `Generic<int>` and `Nested<int>`?

Comment: Of course there can be a legitimate reason. Here's an example from the BCL of .NET. The public class [AdjustmentRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule) is nested inside the public class [System.TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo). The reason is that _adjustment rules_ are kind of "subordinated" _time zone informations_. Another example is when a nested `private` class lives inside another class. This could be because the inner class is needed only as a kind of implementation detail of the containing class.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm going to explain that with an example from the BCL. `List<int>.Enumerator` is different from `List<float>.Enumerator`. This also makes it obvious that it's an enumerator belonging to that list type, which is clearer (imo) than `ListEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: @Antonijn: Same example: `ListEnumerator<int>` is different from `ListEnumerator<float>`.  This also lets you use one type for similar containers, which can be a better design.

Comment: @MooingDuck That approach would seem to leak implementation details. E.g. `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` has a nested `Enumerator` class which needs to know the underlying implementation of the collection - in this case, that it is essentially a hash-table. Another dictionary type might use a tree structure internally, or even just a different hash-table mechanism (e.g. chaining vs. cuckoo hashing), all would need different enumerators, making it impossible to define a separate `DictionaryEnumerator<K,V>` type that would be in any way reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm this might call for a very suggestive answer and therefore many will disagree with my answer. I am one of those people who believe that there is no real need for nested classes and I am tended to agree with your statement:

> > My 'gut instinct' in this regard is that doing so is simply due to extremely poor methodology

Cases where people feel the need to design nested classes is where functionality that is tightly coupled to the behavior designed in the outer class. E.g. event handling can be designed in an inner class, or the `Threading` behavior can find its way to inner classes.

I rather refactor specific behavior out of the 'outer' class so that I end up with two smaller classes that both have clear responsibilities.

To me the main drawback of designing inner classes is that they tend to clutter functionality which is hard(er) to use with principals as [TDD](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (test driven development).

If you are not relying on test driven principals, I think it will not harm you a lot. It is (like so many things) a matter of taste, not a matter of right or wrong. I learned that the topic can lead to long and exhausting discussion. Quite similar to whether you should use `static` helper classes that tend to do more than just 'be a helper' and are getting more and more state over time.

The discussions can become a lot more concrete if you ever run into a real life example. Until then it will be mostly people's "gut feeling".

Answer (score 1):

Common uses for nested classes in C# include classes that are for internal use by your class that ou don't want exposed in your module's internal namespace. For example, you may need to throw an exception that you don't expose to the outside world. In that case you would want to make it a nested class so that others can't use it.

Another example is a binary tree's `Node` class. Not only would it be something you wouldn't want exposed outside of your class, but it might need access to private members for internal operations.

Answer (score 0):

One area where you encounter nested classes quite frequently (although perhaps without noticing) is enumerators (i.e. classes implementing `IEnumerator<T>`).

In order for a collection to support multiple simultaneous enumerations (e.g. on multiple threads, or even just nested `foreach` loops over the same collection), the enumeration logic needs to be separated from the collection into another class.

However, enumerators often need specific knowledge of the implementation details of a collection in order to work correctly. If you were to do this with an entirely separate (non-nested) class, you'd have to make those internals more accessible than they really should be, thus breaking encapsulation. (One could perhaps argue that it could be done using `internal` members, but I think this still breaks encapsulation to some extent, even if it is "only" exposing implementation details to the members of the same assembly).

By using a private nested class for the enumerator, these problems go away whilst maintaining proper encapsulation, since the nested class can access the internals of its containing class.

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons with having nested classes. The pros center around deliberate uses such as `IEnumerator<T>` that Iridium mentioned and nesting classes to facilitate the [Command Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in) in [WPF/MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). SQL Create, Read, Update and Delete (CRUD)  operations are popular to encapsulate in classes/commands in code using these patterns for Line of Business / Data-driven apps.

Negatives associated with nesting classes are associated with debugging - the more classes you nest, the greater the complexity, the easier it is introduce bugs, the harder it is to debug it all. Even using something like the Command Pattern, as organizing as it is, can bloat your Class with too many classes/commands.